# How @supports directive works in Safari iOS

Tags: ios, css, web, safari, responsive

My web application is responsive and I must support iOS 10 and later.
I have a container which height is dynamic. In order to deal with iPhone X layout I'm using `@supports` directive as described here: [iPhone X layout features with CSS Environment variables](https://medium.com/@draganeror/iphone-x-layout-features-with-css-environment-variables-d57423433dec).

This is the code I've implemented so far (do not take into account `90px` since is just an example):

```
const wrapperWhenCollapsed = {
  height: 'calc(100% - 90px)',
  '@supports (padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top))': {
    height: 'calc(100% - 90px - constant(safe-area-inset-bottom))',
  },
  '@supports (padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top))': {
    height: 'calc(100% - 90px - env(safe-area-inset-bottom))',
  },
};

const wrapperWhenExpanded = {
  height: '100%',
  '@supports (padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top))': {
    height: 'calc(100% - constant(safe-area-inset-bottom))',
  },
  '@supports (padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top))': {
    height: 'calc(100% - env(safe-area-inset-bottom))',
  },
};
```

Based on this I have few questions:

- What's the purpose of `padding-top` within the `@supports` directive?
- Is there a way to use `@supports` directive without using `padding-top`?

My goal is to just verify the browser support `constant` or `env`. If not the fallback value is applied.

Thanks, Lorenzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What's going on.

Think of `@supports` the same as `@media` its basically an if/else check that the browser understands.

In the case of @supports, you need to provide a valid CSS rule to parse. The problem is that CSS `env()` is part of a value declaration in CSS. Therefore to correctly match as "valid" @supports needs a matching attribute name to check that the entire rule works.

Since `env()` would be valid as part of a layout declaration `padding-top` was chosen. You could likely use `padding`, `margin` etc instead. **It just has to be a valid parseable rule.**

---

### Device testing

If your goal is to target a specific device, I'd be really careful using `@supports` as that's intended to tell you what the browser can do NOT specifically what device is being used. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc are all going to tell you that `env()` [is valid](https://caniuse.com/#search=env()). While only Safari (older versions) support `constant()` in place of `env()`. **Now it's been deprecated.**

In this case, what you're really testing is that `safe-area-inset-*` exists and has a value not that the CSS render engine supports a specific attribute.

---

Since you're using Javascript to set this you should be able to avoid all the `@supports` stuff and simply test the variable with JS. (I haven't tested this since I don't have access to the device)

```
var safe = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('safe-area-inset-top');
if(safe && safe != null) {
  // is iPhoneX so do your thing
  // or maybe another phone with a notch...
}
```

*Note, I don't know what exactly you should expect back if it's valid. But I assume you'll get a pixel dimension so test that it exists and for a value.*

---

All that said, you really shouldn't test for a specific device/browser combo. Instead, you should build code that will adapt to different devices. Meaning any phone with a notch vs iPhone X.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. Is this apply for an application written in Cordova? I think in this case `@supports` could be a good solution since 'safe-area-inset-top' is valid only for iOS WebKit, not Android one.

Comment: Well the js should work with Cordova BUT I don't know exactly which lifecycle hook you'd need to use. I believe `getComputedStyle()` needs to wait until the DOM is fully rendered and I don't know when the `env()` vars are actually available either.

Answer (score 1):

In case of your `height` property, you shouldn't need to use `@supports` since any browser that doesn't recognize `env()` or `constant()` will fall back to your default value (`calc(100% - 90px)` or `100%`).

As to how to use `@supports`, you can use it with any CSS property/value combination. It detects whether the user's browser supports a specific CSS feature. Some examples:

```
@supports (display: grid) { /* Browser supports grid layout */ }
@supports (color: #ffff) { /* Browser supports RGBA hex colors */ }
@supports (--foo: 123) { /* Browser supports CSS variables */ }
```